# In Excel, how to get the count of records with the first column larger than 1 and the second column larger than 2?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a Excel table with many rows. Each record/row has two columns of number.

How to get the count of records (rows) with the first column larger than 1 and the second column larger than 2?

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried the `CountIfs` function?

```
=COUNTIFS(A:A,">1",B:B,">2")
```

This counts only those where both conditions evaluate true, I think this is what you desire.

Example:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

David's solution is the right one.

As an alternative you can use `SUMPRODUCT`

`=SUMPRODUCT((A:A>1)*(B:B>2))`